# Can I have a filtered column in excel be placed into a PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-powerpoint

I have an excel file that has two main columns:

- `Name` column with all unique values
- `Status` column with values ranging from 1-5.  Is it possible to have the filtered view of the table linked to a PowerPoint presentation so that it only shows the Names colomn

Example of table:

```
| Names | Status |
|:------|:-------|
| D53   | 3      |
| D51   | 1      |
| G09   | 3      |
| F92   | 5      |
| J92   | 3      |
```

Example of desired output for status 3:

```
D53
G09
J92
```

Comment: Placing a spreadsheet object in the PPTX may do what you want

Comment: Hi and welcome to Superuser . It's not entirely clear what you're trying to put in the PowerPoint, is it simply the whole Name column? If not, what is it that you want to see there?

Comment: I am looking to only add the names to the power point if they have a status value of 3.  I am in Office 16 so am not able to use Filter() which would make ot easier

Comment: Maybe something like this C1 (and drag down) to get the list? `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$B$12, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($D$1,$B$2:$B$12), MATCH(ROW($A$2:$B$12), ROW($A$2:$B$12)), ""), ROWS(C$1:$C1)), COLUMNS($A$2:A2)),"")` (where B1 has the status number you want, `3`)